# Application-Based Operating System...?

Tags: windows, operating-system, iso

So I wanted to create an operating system that was *Purely* for running a windows application. Is there any way to do this, and what is the name of an application-based operating system? 
***This application doesn't import to any place like appdata, program files (program files x86) or any %windir% directory, it just stays in the folder with the .exe***

### ***UPDATE***

*Do NOT just say "OH IT'S SOOO HARD DON'T DO IT" I need a program (That makes an OS) that can be based off of an application.*

Comment: Creating an OS is no trivial task. It requires extreme programming knowledge and a whole lot of work. Also, EXEs are proprietary so you'd have to create a decoder. If you do end up trying to create an OS, I recommend that you build your application in a more universal language (for example C or C++). That way all you have to do is create an OS that runs C code. Still, this is way too much work. You should look into just using Windows and make your [program the only one available to your users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136816/making-windows-run-only-one-program-visible-to-the-user).

Comment: Are you an alien life-form?

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, I am an Alien.

Comment: There are several issues with this question which you might try to address: (1) you don't actually pose a *specific* programming problem; (2) it would help if you provided more context -- perhaps if people understood **what you were trying to accomplish** they would give you suggestions that would actually help.  Simply insisting that you want an answer won't be as helpful as giving people a good reason -- they will be more inclined to try to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you really want to build your own operating system. There's already an operating system called [ReactOS](http://www.reactos.org/) that's pretty much what you're looking to build.

Just to reemphasize that creating an operating system isn't easy (especially one that runs Windows applications), ReactOS development started in 1998 and they're still in alpha stage.

If you still want to have a crack at it, I would recommend having a look at [OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Expanded_Main_Page), [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) source code and [ReactOS](http://www.reactos.org/) source code.

Have you considered perhaps making a minimalistic Linux distro that contains the minimum number of programs needed to start up Wine and the Windows application you need?